# Preserve Cloudfront brotli compression through a nginx reverse_proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, compression, amazon-cloudfront

My question is similar to [Nginx reverse-proxy to a cloudfront distribution and preserve gzip compression](https://serverfault.com/questions/889198/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-a-cloudfront-distribution-and-preserve-gzip-compression) but especially regarding the new brotli compression algorithm that is supposed to perform better than gzip in some cases

My AWS Cloudfront Distribution supports brotli

[image]

But my website is behind a nginx proxy for various reason, and when proxy_passing the request to cloudfront, I'm losing the brotli compression and I only get gzip.

I have activated gzip compression and gzip_proxied, is there an equivalent that would allow either gzip or brotli compression to be preserved from the cloudfront distribution ? I've heard of brotli modules for nginx and answers of 2017 ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206812/how-can-i-use-nginx-brotli-static-with-proxy-pass)) that mentioned proxy_pass with nginx + brotli wasn't possible, is it still the case ?

```
server { 
  ...
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_min_length 256;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types *;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli/issues/53) clarification. The ngx_brotli developer mentions that something like `brotli_proxied` isn't required, as it will compress proxied requests by default.

```
server { 
  ...
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_min_length 256;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types *;

  brotli on;
  ...
}
```

Should be sufficient. If the upstream (Cloudfront, in this case) does/serves Brotli compressed assets, then NGINX will simply pass those back to the client as they are, without doing Brotli compression twice.